# Execute function when button is pressed, not when script runs

Tags: python, function, tkinter, command

I have come up with this code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def browse():
    inputfilename=askopenfilename()
    return inputfilename

def fileManipulator(infile=browse(),outfile="C:\\out\\File.kml"):
    #code that manipulates the file here
    file.save(outfile)

root=tkinter.Tk()
browseButton=tkinter.Button(root,text="Browse",command=browse)
browseButton.pack()
fileButton=tkinter.Button(root,text="Manipulate file",command=fileManipulator)
fileButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The code gives me a GUI with two buttons. The *Browse* button is supposed to let the user browse through the input file. The *Manipulate File* button is supposed to process that file and save the file output somewhere.

The problem I am facing is that the browse `askopenfilename` function is executing as soon as I run the script.That happens because I am calling the function inside the definition of the fileManipulator function. The reason I am calling the function inside fileManipulator is obviously because I want to use the path that askopenfilename returns as input file.

Is there a workaround to not execute the `askopenfilename` immediately, but when the *Browse* button is pressed?

**EDITS:** I also don't want the browse() function to be executed again when I press the *File Manipulator* button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** For the updated requirement -

> Sorry, I should have added some more details. Your solutions work well in that the browse() function is not executing immediately now. However, apart from that, I also want that the GUI prompts the user only once with the Browse dialog box. In your solution, the user is prompted once when they press Browse, and another time when they press File Mnipulator. I also edited my question to reflect what I am looking for.

If so, I guess you could define some kind of `global` variable, that is updated when `browse()` is called, and use that instead. If the global variable is `None` or whatever default , meaning you are first time calling `file Manipulate` , then make your function call the `browse()` method. Example -

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
inputfile = None
def browse():
    global inputfile
    inputfile=askopenfilename()

def fileManipulator(outfile="C:\\out\\File.kml"):
    global inputfile
    if inputfile is None:
        browse()
    #code that manipulates the file here
    file.save(outfile)

root=tkinter.Tk()
browseButton=tkinter.Button(root,text="Browse",command=browse)
browseButton.pack()
fileButton=tkinter.Button(root,text="Manipulate file",command=fileManipulator)
fileButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

**FOR ORIGINAL ISSUE:**

The issue is that the default parameters for a function are executed when the function gets defined (not when it is called) , this is the main reason for GOTCHAs like *Mutable Default Arguments* , and your issue .

If you want to be able to send in `infile` as a parameter, and also be able to use `browse()` function, if it is not provided. I would suggest you to use `**kwargs` . Example -

```
def fileManipulator(outfile="C:\\out\\File.kml",**kwargs):
    if 'infile' in kwargs:
        infile = kwargs['infile']
    else:
        infile = browse()
    #code that manipulates the file here
    file.save(outfile)
```

---

Another simpler method would be to use a default value like `None` or so , and then if the `infile` is `None` , use `browse()` method -

```
def fileManipulator(infile=None,outfile="C:\\out\\File.kml"):
    if infile is None:
        infile=browse()
    #code that manipulates the file here
    file.save(outfile)
```

But this differs from what you originally tried, as in, if you call the function as - `fileManipulator(infile=None)` , this would cause `browse()` function to be called.

---

Lastly, If you do not need the `infile` / `outfile` as arguments, don't define them as default arguments, rather define them in the body of the function -

```
def fileManipulator():
    infile=browse()
    outfile="C:\\out\\File.kml"
    #code that manipulates the file here
    file.save(outfile)
```

---

Relevant part from [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

> **Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is executed.** This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used for each call.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added some more details. Your solutions work well in that the browse() function is not executing immediately now. However, apart from that, I also want that the GUI prompts the user only once with the Browse dialog box. In your solution, the user is prompted once when they press Browse, and another time when they press File Mnipulator. I also edited my question to reflect what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok so let me get it straight, you want the browse() button to show up when you first click on file manipulate , but if its clicked second time, you do not want to call browse again ?

Comment: I want three things:
1. When executing the script, a GUI with two buttons is shown and nothing else happens
2. When pressing the Browse button, the user is prompted with the browse dialog and then selects the file in the file system.
3. When pressing the File Manipulator button, the script processes the file that the user selected in step 2 and doesn't ask prompt again with the browse dialog. 

Currently, the browse dialog is still appearing when File Manipuator is prssed.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem this was my solution:

```
self.button = Button(self, text="Preview", command=lambda: runFunction(arg0,arg1,arg2))
```